# Transforming data with multiple column and row labels into database structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Excel files in this format with multiple labels for columns and rows:

|  |  |  | col label A1 | col label A2 | col label A3 | … | col label A99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | col label B1 | col label B1 | col label B2 | … | col label B99 |
|  |  |  | col label C1 | col label C1 | col label C2 | … | col label C99 |
| row label A | row label B | row label C |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| row label A1 | row label B1 | row label C1 | x | x | x | x | x |
| row label A2 | row label B1 | row label C1 | x | x | x | x | x |
| row label A3 | row label B2 | row label C1 | x | x | x | x | x |

and I want to transfer it into an ordinary DB structure like this:

| row label A | row label B | row label C | col label A | col label B | col label C | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| row label A1 | row label B1 | row label C1 | col label A1 | col label A2 | col label A3 | x |
| row label A2 | row label B1 | row label C1 | col label B1 | col label B1 | col label B2 | x |
| row label A3 | row label B2 | row label C1 | col label C1 | col label C1 | col label C2 | x |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | … |
| row label A99 | row label B99 | row label C99 | col label A99 | col label B99 | col label C99 | x |

I think the best way would be with a Pandas Dataframe? But even here I am not completely sure whether this is the best approach.

Happy for any kind of help!

Comment: Your input is ambiguous, do you have columns? a MultiIndex? empty rows? Please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` for clarity and reproducibility

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. I have no df yet. Currently I want to read an XLS file into a df. Basically, the XLS file has three columns that are used as label for the first three rows. All other columns (around 90) have three indices for each column. Any other input needed to resolve the ambiguity?